# The name "streamlit" is not recognized as a cmdlet name

Tags: python, streamlit

I wanna run the following code - `PS C:\Users\1\Desktop\st-media-server-master> streamlit run client_app.py`. But then I got this issue

```
streamlit : The name "streamlit" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable. Check the spelling of the name and the presence and correctness of the path, then try again.
string:1 character:1
+ streamlit
+ ~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (streamlit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What I should do?

In the `client_app.py` i have `import streamlit as st`. Also I have installed the `streamlit` by pip command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the command `python -m streamlit run client_app.py`. Alternatively, add Python to Windows PATH: https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: `C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: No module named streamlit`

Comment: Where did you install streamlit? Have you installed it in an environment (venv/anaconda) or just globally through pip?

Comment: thank you, I noticed that i installed globally